# How to detect and handle high speed collisions in java

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project that requires moving rectangles around the screen with the mouse, and I've run into an issue. The way I have been detecting collisions in other projects where objects are controlled using the keyboard is to split the objects boundaries into left, right, top, and bottom boundaries, and handle the collisions accordingly. But in this case, the mouse is controlling the objects and if I move the mouse too fast it mistakes a top collision for a left or right collision. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You're going to have a number of issues, mostly relating to the fact mouse events are delivered in small increments, as you move the mouse faster, the distance between the events become greater.  What you might need to do is determine the path from mouse event to another and calculate the possible collisions between those points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to do an interpolation between mouse coordinates. If the distance between current mouse coordinate and the previous one is larger than a value (lets say 20) you may begin an iteration with 20px increments and check for the collusion at those points. That way you would catch the collusion and handle it at the correct moment.